# Why does Flutter FirebaseAuth signInWithEmailAndPassword throw an invalid-credential exception?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have the code below in my Flutter app. I am calling it with known good email and password values, but I am hitting the 'invalid-credential' case. I have `firebase_auth: ^4.16.0` in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (exception) {
  switch (exception.code) {
    case 'invalid-credential':

rest of catch block...
```

I even tried disabling email enumeration protection, based on a comment here: [Firebase issue thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11713), but that didn't fix the problem. I'm happy to provide any other necessary information.

The user was created by successfully calling

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
```

The issue happens with several accounts.

Comment: Disabling email enumeration protection is literally the answer to this question in the [documentation for this API (in JS)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#signinwithemailandpassword_21ad33b).  Since that error message is coming from Google's backend, there's not much you can do other than follow the given instructions.  If you feel that you're getting an incorrect response from Firebase Auth and you're unable to resolve it by using those instructions (or simply changing the password), then reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) for assistance.

Comment: When I disable email enumeration protection, I get a 'wrong-password' error, even with a correct password. Thanks for the link to Firebase support.

Comment: How did you create your user? is it happening with an other account? did you check the password value?

Comment: @FaBotch I added info to my question which answers your first two questions. I am 100% certain that I am using correct passwords.

Comment: Can you try with an user created via the console?

Comment: @FaBotch Logging with a user created via the console works, so now I'm really confused. `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);` doesn't throw an exception, but users created that way cause the `wrong-password` exception when signing in.

Comment: Are your password entered by code or setup by user via a form? Did you try / catch createUserWithEmailAndPassword ? is it on iOS or Android or web or other platform?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256629/discussion-between-carl-smith-and-fabotch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the kind help of @Doug Stevenson and @FaBotch, I found a simple mistake in my createUserWithEmailAndPassword call. Thanks for your time and patience.